LLamaIndex ImportError: Cannot Import Name: BaseQueryEngine from llama_index.core
Just installed llama index and was trying to run the most basic program but getting an import error.
Here is how I installed it:
pip llama-index

Here is my full source:
from llama_index.core import VectorStoreIndex, SimpleDirectoryReader

docs = SimpleDirectoryReader("data").load_data()

I also tried installing
pip llama-index-core 

I tried reinstalling llama-index still get this error about a class I am not directly importing.

Note: the code works fine from another venv so i am thinking its a versioning issue? I just installed latest llama-index

can you share the error? I think Llama Index was using a different module structure in the past so that might be the problem. Otherwise, can this be a problem related to your venv setup?

just realised the error is in the title of the question...

The setup using pip install llama-index is correct, so I think the problem must be in your venv configuration.
